# jsonb acess array element

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb value like this in my Postgres database:

```
{
   "data":[
      [
         {
            "id":"identity_phone_1",
            "type":"string",
            "class":"col-md-6",
            "label":"Téléphone",
            "value":"tamereenslip"
         },
         {
            "id":"identity_imei_1",
            "type":"string",
            "class":"col-md-6",
            "label":"IMEI",
            "value":"d"
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "id":"identity_phone_2",
            "type":"string",
            "class":"col-md-6",
            "label":"Téléphone",
            "value":"e"
         },
         {
            "id":"identity_imei_2",
            "type":"string",
            "class":"col-md-6",
            "label":"IMEI",
            "value":"f"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

I need to access automatically to all of the `value` field. For now I find the right command but it's not automatic, I need the `0`'s to increment automatically, is it possible?

```
phones #>> '{data, 0, 0, value}'
```

Edit : I want to retrieve all the values in one command :

`tamerenslip`, `d`, `e`, `f`

Also, I need to put this command in a select :/

Comment: What do you mean with "increment automatically". Please **[edit]** your question and add the result you expect from the query

Comment: Should that be 4 different columns, or one column where the values are separated with a comma?

Comment: Also: which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
with invar as (
select '{
   "data":[
      [
         {
            "id":"identity_phone_1",
            "type":"string",
            "class":"col-md-6",
            "label":"Téléphone",
            "value":"tamereenslip"
         },
         {
            "id":"identity_imei_1",
            "type":"string",
            "class":"col-md-6",
            "label":"IMEI",
            "value":"d"
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "id":"identity_phone_2",
            "type":"string",
            "class":"col-md-6",
            "label":"Téléphone",
            "value":"e"
         },
         {
            "id":"identity_imei_2",
            "type":"string",
            "class":"col-md-6",
            "label":"IMEI",
            "value":"f"
         }
      ]
   ]
}'::jsonb as jdata
), getkey as (
  select jsonb_array_elements(jdata->'data') array1
    from invar
), idx1 as (
  select jsonb_array_elements(array1) array2
    from getkey
)
select array2->>'value' as value
  from idx1;

    value     
--------------
 tamereenslip
 d
 e
 f
(4 rows)
```

**Update**

```
with getkey as (
  select jsonb_array_elements(phones->'data') as array1
    from individu_identity
), idx1 as (
  select jsonb_array_elements(array1) array2
    from getkey
)
select array2->>'value' as value
  from idx1
 where translate(array2->>'value', ..., ...) ...
;
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your help. The solution could be good, but it's not working as expected because I have to put that into a `translate()` function located in the `WHERE` of my request. Also, the `data` json wasn't hardcoded, I try but I can't modify your peice of code using `SELECT phones #> '{}' from individu_identity`. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Nathan30 Updated the answer to show how to query from the table and how to use the value in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update ! 
Last questions, if I want to delete the JSONB element if value is equal to "f", is there a possiblity to do it ? By keeping other JSONB element

Comment: @Nathan30 Can you clarify what you mean by `delete`? If you want to remove it from your output list, then add `array2->>'value' != 'f'` in your `where` clause.  If you want to remove it from the stored JSONB, then you need to perform an `update` to the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want those values as a comma separated string, you can use this:

```
select ...., x.elements
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
    select string_agg(item.element ->> 'value', ', ') elements
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.phone -> 'data') as p(items)
      cross join jsonb_array_elements(p.items) as item(element)
  ) x
```

Replace `...` with the other columns from the table you want to display.